# Who coined the genre “indie”?

Tags: history, genre

I know that “indie” is short for independent to refer to a band’s record label but overtime it grew to encompass a music genre.

When/who does “indie” (ex. Indie rock, indie folk) as a genre identifier trace back to?

Comment: This article isn't specific about who coined the term — and when — but it does give a general answer: [Explainer: indie music](https://theconversation.com/explainer-indie-music-28321).

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Buzzcocks, *Spiral Scratch*, 1977

---

> According to the BBC documentary *Music for Misfits: The Story of Indie*, 1977 was the year indie music was born. The Buzzcocks, a band from Manchester, released an EP independently of a major label and coined the term indie. (Source: [What is Indie Music? 10 Top Examples](https://www.musicindustryhowto.com/what-is-indie-music/), by Liam Duncan, 10 Dec 2021)

> The BBC documentary Music for Misfits: The Story of Indie[25] pinpoints the birth of indie as the 1977 self-publication of the Spiral Scratch EP by Manchester band Buzzcocks. Although Buzzcocks are often classified as a punk band, it has been argued by the BBC and others that the publication of Spiral Scratch independently of a major label led to the coining of the name "indie". (Source: Wikipedia, [Indie Rock, History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indie_rock#History))

> It is thought that the first example of a band publishing their own record was the 1977 Spiral Scratch EP by Buzzcocks. (Source: ["A History of Indie"](https://web.archive.org/web/20170408103321/http://www.23indie.com:80/indiemusicdefined.html), by Richard Copley for 23 Indie Street)

---

[Etymology.com adds](https://www.etymonline.com/word/indie) some interesting history, pointing out that the term was first used in the context of film production companies in the 1920s.